# SQL query works but data is corrupting?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that works fine when searching for data for 1 game only `WHERE gameid = 36`, however once I try to join multiple games `gameid = 36 AND gameid = 37`  the query runs fine but returns all 0's for all data

```
SELECT 
 CONCAT_WS(  '. ', SUBSTR( p.playerfname, 1, 1 ) , p.playerlname ) name, 
 COALESCE( goalEvents.goals, 0 ) goals, 
 COALESCE( a1.assists, 0 ) + COALESCE( a2.assists, 0 ) assists, 
 COALESCE( goalEvents.goals, 0 ) + COALESCE( a1.assists, 0 ) + COALESCE( a2.assists, 0 ) points
FROM players p
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT scorer, COUNT( scorer ) goals FROM goalEvents WHERE gameid = 36 AND gameid = 37GROUP BY scorer) goalEvents ON p.playerid = goalEvents.scorer
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT assist1, COUNT( assist1 ) assists FROM goalEvents WHERE gameid = 36 AND gameid = 37 GROUP BY assist1) a1 ON p.playerid = a1.assist1
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT assist2, COUNT( assist2 ) assists FROM goalEvents WHERE gameid = 36 AND gameid = 37 GROUP BY assist2) a2 ON p.playerid = a2.assist2
WHERE p.playerteam = 26 ORDER BY points DESC, goals DESC
```

There error must occur with the multiple game lines being called

```
FROM goalEvents WHERE gameid = 36 AND gameid = 37
```

Am I searching by multiple games wrong? Im basically trying to search by the last 4 gameids of my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
FROM goalEvents WHERE gameid = 36 OR gameid = 37
```

You will need to use `OR` instead of `AND`, gameid can never be 36 `AND` 37. You want to find two different records, one with `gameid=36` and another with `gameid=37`. If you use `AND` they both fail the condition.

If you have more than 2, you can also try `gameid IN (36, 37, ...)` it is short hand for `OR`, `OR`, `OR` etc

Comment: but I want to get stats from both those games and add them together, I can get stats from all the games with the same query if I dont specify a gameid, im trying to get stats from specific games and add them all up

Comment: Still, you cannot use `gameid=36 AND gameid=37` for the first game where with gameid=36 it is only 36, that record is would fail the `AND gameid=37`. Does it not work with OR?

Comment: i think I get what you are saying now, let me try OR

Answer (score 1):

you can use `IN` CLAUSE I think that will do the trick

like try this out

```
FROM goalEvents WHERE gameid in(36,37)
```

best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FROM goalEvents WHERE gameid in (36, 37);
```

I guess gameid is unique so you can't use `and` as it is not possible that gameid to be 36 and 37 in one row. So try using `in`